# Associate MP3 with iOS app, "Open with..."

Tags: ios, info.plist

I have an iOS app I've already associated with ZIP files like so:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>ZIP Archive</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>zip</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>application/zip</string>
            <string>application/x-zip</string>
            <string>application/x-zip-compressed</string>
        </array>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.pkware.zip-archive</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

**And this works as expected.** When a user clicks a ZIP to download in Safari, my app comes up as an app to "Open with".

---

I'd like the same functionality for MP3. I've tried the following to no avail (app doesn't come up in the list). I've also tried subtle variations:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>beer-mug.png</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string></string>
        </array>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.mp3</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>public.audio</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

This image sums up what I'm going for:

[image]

Are MP3 files "protected" or something? I need a way for users to be able to download/access MP3 files in my iOS app (use as sound effects).

Surprisingly searching is coming up empty. Ideally someone with this MP3 functionality in their app posting their info.plist would be super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Why is your setup for mp3 so different than your setup for zip? The following fixes should work:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>ZIP Archive</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>zip</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>application/zip</string>
            <string>application/x-zip</string>
            <string>application/x-zip-compressed</string>
        </array>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.pkware.zip-archive</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>MP3</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>mp3</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>audio/mpeg</string>
            <string>audio/mpeg3</string>
            <string>audio/mpg</string>
            <string>audio/mp3</string>
        </array>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.mp3</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```